# correctly allow polymorphic behavior in wrappers

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, wrapper

Given a templated wrapper of some type T

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
  T* value;
};
```

if I want to give the wrapper some polymorphic behaviour, I usually use some templated operators with sfinae. A ctor for example:

```cpp
template<typename Base>
template<typename Derived, enable_if_t<is_base_of<T,From>::value,int> = 0>
Wrapper<Base>::Wrapper(Wrapper<Derived> & other) : value(other.value) {
}
```

and it works with simple cases. However, when I start creating compelx hierarchical structures, I find the compiler not understanding what is going on. A very silly code would be

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    int i;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(int in) {
        this->i = in;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Wrapper {
  Wrapper(T & v) : value(&v) {}
  T* value;
};

template<typename T>
struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual T const & get() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Something : Interface<T> {
    Something(Wrapper<T> const & value) : pt(&value) {}
    Wrapper<T>* pt;
    T const & get() {return pt->value;}
};

void foo(unique_ptr<Interface<Base>> && p) {
    std::cout << "I have interface to base" << p->get()->i;
}

int main() {
    Derived v(42);
    Wrapper<Derived> w(v);
    foo(make_unique<Something<Derived>>(w) );
}
```

In this kind of code, Something derives from Interface, and Derived from Base, so it should be possible, in principle, to go from `unique_ptr<Something<Derived>>` to `unique_ptr<Interface<Base>>` and I believe there is no great danger in doing it.

Which operators (ctors, assign, conversions, etc..) you would define with the SFINAE/is_base_of mechanism? Where? Are there some general rules to follow?

Comment: Off Topic: your `Something` constructor assign to `pt` the pointer to `value` that could be a temporary object. This can lead to a dangling reference at the end of construction.

Comment: right, it should be "Wrapper<T> &"

Comment: Your `wrapper<T>` contains a `T`, for polymorphism to apply, you need (smart) pointer on `T`... Else you will have object slicing.

Comment: also right, I modify to clear things up. The main focus is about the interface. In main I do not wish to convert Derived to Base, but say that interface works also for Base.

Answer (score 0):

> Something derives from Interface, and Derived from Base, so it should be possible, in principle, to go from `unique_ptr<Something<Derived>>` to `unique_ptr<Interface<Base>>`

C++ templates are not co-variant.  There is no relationship between `Interface<Derived>` and `Interface<Base>`.  And in general, it would not be type-safe.  Your particular `Interface` class only returns the type in a covariant sense, but other examples could easily accept parameters of the type, which would be contravariant.

Tacking `unique_ptr` or `Wrapper` onto these two unrelated types doesn't change the situation.  You have no polymorphic behavior for the wrapper (smart pointer) type to preserve.

Comment: I'm not telling that it should be done automatically, but that for some particular cases, the conversion should be allowed by giving some special templated operators such as ctors, conversions, etc.. STL does this all the time, for example allowing unique_ptr<Base> being built from unique_ptr<Derived>

Comment: @Teloze: Yes, it's possible for a wrapper to pass-through polymorphic usage of related types.  **This does not creation a relationship between the wrapper types even though they sort-of act related.**  And because `Interface<Base>` and `Interface<Derived>` are unrelated, there is no polymorphic behavior to pass through.  The failure happens at `Interface`, not at `unique_ptr` or `Wrapper`.

Comment: and what's wrong in defining ```template<Base>template<Derived>Interface<Base>::Interface(Interface<Derived> const &)``` if due precautions are done in allowing this function only if ```Base test() { return std::declval<Derived>(); } ``` is well formed ? That is what Interface does.

Comment: @Telzone: I didn't say that doing that was wrong, I said that it doesn't make the types related.  Convertible is much weaker than related.  Convertible means that given an instance of T, you can get a new different object that is an instance of U.  Related requires that the instance of T is itself an instance of U, with no new object involved.  When you wrap related types T and U in `Interface`, you get `Interface<T>` being convertible to `Interface<U>` but they are unrelated.

Comment: so, if I understand well, that prevents the upcast in principle and I should create a new unique_ptr<Interface<T>> from the conversion of Interface<U> to Interface<T>

Comment: @Teloze: If all you're doing is reading object attibutes, that will probably work.  As soon as you try writing or state changes, the fact that you're working on a new converted object and not the original is going to become a very big issue.